# Can not fix the Display rotation in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: display, display-rotation

After installing Ubuntu 17.10, the display screen is not in normal position, such landscape, but in portrait instead; how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried many methods and following many comments, and now I find the answer:

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> then it goes to the login screen, after being logged in the screen comes back to its correct position.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still running 16, but do you have `/usr/bin/unity-control-center`?
If you do, try running it and click on the `Displays` icon. There should be a Rotation pulldown.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the fix was to use the proprietary NVIDIA driver. I was using the "X.Org X server - Nouveau display driver from `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` (open-source)."

I went to Software & Updates > Additional Drivers tab:

[image: use proprietary NVIDIA driver]

It helped to navigate on the rotated screen by connecting my laptop to an external monitor which temporarily made everything rotated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the screen rotation from the terminal with `xrandr -o <rotation>`.

Options for `rotation` are `normal`, `inverted`, `left`, `right`.  Or you can use the numbers `0`,`1`,`2`,`3`, for rotations starting from `normal`, going counter-clockwise.