# There's no orientation setting in the display settings

Tags: 18.04, settings, display-rotation

Ubuntu Version: 18.04
platform: tablet

I can use "xrandr --output DSI-1 --rotate right" to rotate the display.
But there is NO orientation options in the Settings --> Devices --> Display.
Could I enable the orientation options in the settings??

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: can we see a screenshot of your settings?

Comment: In some cases I simply click the resolution and one of the options are the same resolution but reversed (1280 x 800 in your case).

Comment: The panel resolution is 800x1280. If I selected 1280x800, the screen would only be displayed in the center of panel (scale down to 800x500).

Comment: The answers for this question may be of relevance - https://askubuntu.com/questions/976533/can-not-fix-the-display-rotation-in-ubuntu-17-10